# FileSystemWatcher does not get notified when a new file is added to Google Drive

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I'm using the following code to check for a new file/change in a specific folder, but it doesn't raise an event when the folder I am checking for is in Google Drive alouth the file shows up in my folder. Creating a file myself in the folder it listens to *does* raise an event.

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher() {
    Path = Google Drive path,
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName,
    Filter = "*.txt",
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};

watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(ActionChecker.FileFound);
```

Is this a problem with my watcher, or the way Google Drive is made?

Comment: you are listening to the changed event. if you want to know new file is created you should use Created event

Comment: Of course! This was originally intended for Dropbox, which creates the file and _after_ that appends the file-content. Seems like Google Drive doesn't modify it after creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872388/steve) pointed out, I should be listening for `watcher.Created` as well.

The code was originally intended for Dropbox, which creates the file and after that appends the file-content, but Google Drive does things differently

Answer (score 0):

The file is not really downloaded. Check the settings of Google Drive or Onedrive and deactivate the space-saving mode. Only then will the files be downloaded immediately and an event will be raised.